# Download Report as Power Point

Tags: crystal-reports, data-visualization, reporting, tableau-desktop

Is there any reporting tool from which I can automate the output as Power Point. I have access to Crystal and Tableau. From Crystal I can only download report as PDF and then paste in the PPT. Tableau I can download as PPT but some formatting issues and I need to manually download as PPT. Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to take a look at [DOMO](https://www.domo.com/) which can:

- render a dashboard as a slideshow on the fly (https://domohelp.domo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043437793-Sharing-Content-Using-Slideshows)
- download a PPT for your dashboard
- allow you to create refreshable ppt based on your own template (https://domohelp.domo.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043437953-Using-the-Domo-PowerPoint-Plugin)

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this option.

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply need to convert the report pages to a brand new PowerPoint file with one slide per each report page?

Any extra needs such as using a PowerPoint template?
Or using an existing "hosting" PowerPoint file and a target page for insertion?

Do you need any resizing or cropping of content before it gets inserted into the PowerPoint file?

What is the frequency at which this is needed?

Comment: The plan is to format the report in reporting application itself and download it as PPT instead of PDF or CSV. This is a monthly report. We were able to create the report in Crystal but Crystal don't have option to download as PPT. We also created the report in Tableau but before downloading to PPT we need lots of formatting. We want to cut down the formatting step. Thank you.

Comment: Do you need any resizing or cropping of content before it gets inserted into the PowerPoint file?

Comment: We just want to download as it is from reporting tool as PPT and send it to customer. Thank you for responding.